# Windows automatically orders files in a folder

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

Using Windows 8.1 here. Say I have a folder with three files:

[image: Alphabetically ordered files]

Now when I rename mFile.txt to bFile.txt, Windows "helpfully" re-orders the files alphabetically, putting it above kFile.txt. In Windows XP, the renamed file would stay exactly where I left it until the folder view was refreshed (eg. hitting F5 or viewing another folder in Explorer and then returning).

A similar thing happens when I paste file(s) into the folder. In Windows XP, the files would appear at the bottom which was great. Very easy to find them. But in Windows 8.1, they distribute themselves in the file listing, effectively randomising their ordering.

While this is a slightly annoying in a folder with a few files, it is infuriating with a folder which has dozens of files - your files can literally disappear off the screen!

Curiously, on a USB pen drive (plugged into the same computer) the files stay where I put them until the view is refreshed (like in Windows XP).

Is there any way to get the Windows XP functionality and disable this auto-arrange? I'm viewing the folder in Details view, if that is relevant.

Comment: In the link listed [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-disable-the-permanent-auto-arrange-setting-in-windows-7-and-8/) you can find information to help you get this to how you would like it.

Comment: Since Windows 7, the auto-arrange is always used by Windows Explorer. try one of the ugly hacks, but this may cause other explorer issues